# VBA Option Explicit fails to detect undeclared variables in Function

Tags: vba

I have always used `Option Explicit` in each module. I never gave it much thought, until now.

Code:

```
Option Explicit

Function ParseJSON(ByVal strJSON As String) As String
    strJSON = "New String"
    'MsgBox (strJSON)
    ParseJSON = strJSON
End Function

Sub Test()
    Dim strJSON As String
    strJSON = "Old String"
    MsgBox (ParseJSON(strJSON))
    MsgBox (strJSON)
End Sub
```

This piece of code is just a test and has nothing to do with JSON. When I run the code, I expected it to throw an error as `strJSON` is never declared in `ParseJSON`, and it should be a new variable as the original one is passed `ByVal` and thus cannot be changed, the last MsgBox() confirms this.

Is there anything that I didn't get? My hunch points to the `ByVal` part., or maybe `Option Explicit` only checks `Sub`?

Comment: add a breakpoint and inspect in watch window,

Comment: Good idea, will do.

Comment: "It should be a new variable as the original one is passed `ByVal`" is incorrect. `ByVal` doesn't create a new variable, it just means the **actual value** of the variable, not a reference, is passed to the procedure calling it. I like the explanation [here](http://www.cpearson.com/Excel/byrefbyval.aspx).

Comment: @BigBen Sorry that I didn't make it more clear: the strJSON inside of the function is a new variable, i.e. effectively using a new variable without declaration.

Comment: Think of it this way: I've passed the actual value of `strJSON` to the function. I immediately then decide I don't want that original value, instead the new value `"New String"`. Not a new variable but a new value.

Answer (score 2):

the point of `Option Explicit` is to have you explicitly declare all variables you're using, and that's what actually happens in `Function ParseJSON(ByVal strJSON As String) As String`: that `strJSON As String` is *declaring* variable `strJSON` you're going to use *inside* the function (and it's also declaring it as of `String` type)

then, you're also giving it a value passed by the calling sub, and that `ByVal` simply means that whatever value the function `strJSON` variable is going to assume it won't affect the calling sub variable (if any, and that may be incidentally named after `strJSON`, but it's distinct from function `strJSON`) you passed the value of

that's why if you try

```
Function ParseJSON(ByVal strJSON As String) As String
    strJSON = Range("A1:A3")
    'MsgBox (strJSON)
    ParseJSON = strJSON
End Function
```

you'll get a run time `type mismatch error` as soon as the `strJSON = Range("A1:A3")` line is processed

and that's why if you try

```
Sub Test()
    Dim strJSON As String
    strJSON = "Old String"
    MsgBox (ParseJSON(Range("A1:A3")))
    MsgBox (strJSON)
End Sub
```

you'll get the same run time `type mismatch error` as soon as the `MsgBox (ParseJSON(Range("A1:A3")))` line is processed

Comment: I've always assumed the *main* aim of `Option Explicit` was to prevent the accidental creation of new variables via typos, and all the associated bugs that results in...

Comment: @TimWilliams, I'm not getting you

Comment: You state "the point of Option Explicit is to have you explicitly declare the type of all variables you're using", but `Option Explicit` only forces you to name all your variables: it doesn't require any type assignments.  My point is that without the directive, even though you may have declared a variable `MyVariable`, the compiler will not flag accidental use of `MyVaraible` as a problem.

Comment: I see. Yes I'll edit my answer to change _"explicitly declare the type of all variables"_ to "_explicitly declare all variables"_

Answer (score 0):

You ARE declaring properly.
In the Test function you declare it as a string with the DIM statement.
And by making it an argument in the function you are also declaring it as a string, for use in the function.

Because the function uses it byVal, and changes you make IN the function, will not affect the value of the string.

It you want to change the value of it, it has to be passed byRef.
ByRef effectively passed the actual variable. - It could be known by a different name even, but any changes will also change the original variable.

byVal is effectively passing a copy of the variable, which you can play about with but not change the original.

Imagine as a piece of paper.
byRef you hand over the actual piece of paper to be marked up 
byVal you hand over a photocopy, but keep the original to yourself.